# Create Custome View in Android

Tags: android, view, textview

I want to create new a custome view like the figure below :
[image]

I use it many times, so I want to create a new View like UserControl in C#. 
 So I create new class extends View class. I want to add 4 text view programmatically and add some method getText or setText ....

Could you guys show me how can I do that? How to display those textView in my custome view?

Thanks

Comment: Just use a horizontally oriented LinearLayout with **weights** (and generic invisible Views as **spacers**). No need for a custom View.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: because i use it for many time, so I want to create a new view

Comment: You might use an **included** xml.

Comment: Doing it **programmatically** would be harder, but not impossible. You'll have to play with the **LayoutParams**, then. But it's like `killing a mosquito with a gun`...

Answer (score 0):

```
`<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="yourheight"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_name"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_name"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_name"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_name"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: ... and where are the **spacers**?

Comment: how can I reuse this layout?

Comment: Use it as a custom ListView row, for instance.